# How to detect lines/arrow that connects two boxes

Tags: lines

Aim is to scan flowchart from top to bottom and get its structure details. 
Used following methodology:
**Edge detection**: it gives all edges, but how to differentiate the edges forming shape and edge that connects 2 shape?

**Connected Component**: this gives all area that are connected but how to differentiate shape and connecting lines?

**Contours detection:** based on contours wrote following code and successfully got the closed area (shape) but how to get connecting lines?

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # grayscale

blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0)

ret3,th3 = cv2.threshold(blur,60,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(th3,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

after this used boundedbox and approxpolydp to get the shape

Please guide how to find the line that connect two boxes and the relation with boxes?

Comment: Please use code markup for greater readability.

Comment: Thanks KP for formatting

Comment: Resolved using junction point identification.